# Why do I get a null reference error when I export Highcharts?

Tags: pdf, highcharts, export, jpeg

What does this error mean? Happens when I download to any format in highcharts, pdf, image..Has anyone encountered this before?

```
Unhandled exception at line 41, column 33
   in http://localhost/scripts/customEvents.js
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'on'
                                       of undefined or null reference
```

Here are my scripts

```
<%--ADD high chart css and js here.--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/highcharts.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/data.js"></script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/customEvents.js"></script>           
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/iestyle.css">
```

I tried different ways to export but everything point to same error..How do I fix this
?

Comment: Just wondering, are all the scripts above highcharts plugins? That means it's pretty simple to use, just include the correct scripts and it should work out of the box. That's good news for people like me yet to learn highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going back to the most basic of my code and the demo in highcharts, it turns out the click event for 'download' button is triggered in customEvents.js instead of exporting.js. After I removed reference to customEvents.js, the download button worked again. However this is not a solution as I also need the customEvents for my mouseover, Hence, this is a bug for highcharts customEvents plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/q46WQ/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>      
      <script src="http://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/customEvents.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var categoryImgs = {
                'Banana': '<img src="/images/2.png"><img>&nbsp;',
                'Orange': '<img src="/images/8.png"><img>&nbsp;',
                'Fruit': '<img src="/images/12.png"><img>&nbsp;',
                'Apple': '<img src="/images/4.png"><img>&nbsp;',
                'Coconut': '<img src="/images/3.png"><img>&nbsp;'
            };

            var totals = new Array();
            var stackTotals = new Array();
            var i = 5, j = 0;
            //totals = HighchartsAdapter
            function reverse() {
                totals.reverse();
            }

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Premium Summary'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Banana', 'Fruit', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Coconut'],
                    labels: {
                        x: 5,
                        useHTML: true,

                        formatter: function () {

                            var n = totals.shift();
                            return '<div class="stacktotal">$' + n + '</div><div id="div1" class="myToolTip' + this.value + '">' + categoryImgs[this.value] + '</div>';
                        },
                        events: {
                            mouseover: function (e) {
                                var elm = e.currentTarget.children.div1.className;

                                switch (elm) {
                                    case "myToolTipBanana":
                                        document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                        $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/2.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                            '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$89</td></tr>' +
                                            '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$150</td></tr>' +
                                            '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$150</td></tr>' +
                                            '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$200.12</td></tr>' +
                                            '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$514.55<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                        break;
                                    case "myToolTipFruit":
                                        document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                        $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/8.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                           '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$400</td></tr>' +
                                           '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$186.76</td></tr>' +
                                           '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$210.23</td></tr>' +
                                           '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$290</td></tr>' +
                                           '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$1086.99<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                        break;
                                    case "myToolTipOrange":
                                        document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                        $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/12.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$258.13</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$150</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$143.50</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$45.78</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$597.41<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                        break;
                                    case "myToolTipApple":
                                        document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                        $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/3.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$212</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$200</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$219</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$71</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$702<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                        break;
                                    case "myToolTipCoconut":
                                        document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "block";
                                        $('#hoverboard').html('<img style="padding-left:7px; padding-bottom: 30px" src="/images/4.png"><img>&nbsp;<div class="desc">39 year old female non smoker - Occupation Class 1</div><table>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Jam</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>$80,000</td><td class="pad">$152</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Fruit</b><span id="italics">&nbsp;&nbsp;(2 Week wait)</td><td>-</td><td class="pad">$100</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td><b>Candy</b></td><td>Nil Excess</td><td class="pad">$143</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr><td colspan="3" class="pad" ><hr /></td></tr><tr><td><span id="policy">Boxes</span></td><td></td><td class="pad">$120</td></tr>' +
                                          '<tr bgcolor="#EDF7F7"><td style="font-size:14px;"><b>Total Premium (Monthly)</b></td><td></td><td class="pad"><b>$515<b></td></tr>' + '</table>');
                                        break;
                                }
                            },
                            mouseout: function () {
                                document.getElementById('hoverboard').style.display = "none";
                                $('#hoverboard').html('');
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },

                linkedTo: 0,
                categories: ['Banana', 'Fruit', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Coconut'],

                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '$' + this.value;
                        }
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black',
                        },
                        formatter: function () {
                            totals[i++] = this.total;
                            return '';
                        },

                    }                    
                },

                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -70,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 20,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.series.name + ', ' + this.x  + ', ' +' $'+ this.y + '<br/>';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        borderWidth:0,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',
                            style: {
                                textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                            },
                            format: '${y}'
                        }                        
                    }

                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'Jam',
                    y:'$' + this.value,
                    data: [200.12, 290, 45.78, 71, 120],
                    color: '#B9B6BA',
                }, {
                    name: 'Fruit',
                    data: [150, 186.76, 150, 200, 100],
                    color: '#E5764C'
                }, {
                    name: 'Candy',
                    data: [89,400, null , 212, 152],
                    color: '#9D8365'
                }, {
                    name: 'Boxes',
                    data: [75.43, 210.23, 143.50, 219, 143],
                    color: '#9F7AC3'
                } ]

            });           

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Then report bug on github, and post here reference, in your answer.

Comment: Bug fixed by Highcharts! :)